# How to resolve Magento 2 (2.4 Version) localhost 500 server error during installation

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to install Magento 2.4 on my (Ubuntu) Linux environment. But it gives me the localhost is currently unable to handle this request error on the webpage.
I try to resolve by giving folder permission following this article [magento2-folder-permission](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions) but nothing works. My old Magento 2 Projects of version (2.3<) works fine but I only face this issue at 2.4 version installation.

I tried to change the php.ini file memory_limit variable setting to 2G, but not get any result.
I tried to install it several times but every time I wind up with this error

[Error occur when Website open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h44rw.png)

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: I get the same 500/502 error trying to install Magento 2.4.0 using composer. var/log/exception.log says "main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist"

Comment: @Nikunj Rawat take a look here if it's the same issue: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318915/magento-2-4-fails-to-install-due-to-missing-composer-config-file-in-composer-hom

Comment: Hello Nikunj Rawat, Set file for folder 777 and for file 666
sudo find /var/www/html/magento/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/html/magento/ -typefd -exec chmod 666 {} \;

Comment: @KrunalPathak it doesn't work for me. Did you install it using composer with success? Fresh install? What's your environment?

Comment: @KaMZaTa, I have not install using composer, I have downloaded zip file and follow https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html

Comment: @Nikunj Rawat do you use a Reverse Proxy in front of it?